# Could not enable Google map Location histroy on huawei M8

Tags: android, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services

just like the screenshot of my phone. Recently(June 2) I could not use and could not enable the location history. When I click the "Location History is off", nothing happened.

I have tried:

2. Verify my google account has enabled the service(location history). I logged in my google account on other devices and could use the location history service.
3. Other user account logged on my Mate8 could not use the location history.( they could use the location history on their device)
4. Tried different versions of google map on Mate 8. no use

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @LukeG. It tuned out to be android security update :). Once M8 released the new update, it works